# Python: Tkinter Entry widget is not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
ticker1 = StringVar()
ticker2 = StringVar()
root.title("Choose Companies")
Label(root,
          text = "Company No. 1",
          fg = "black",
          font ="Helvetica 16 italic").pack()
name = Entry(root,name = ticker1 ).pack()
Label(root,
          text = "Company No. 2",
          fg = "black",
          font ="Helvetica 16 italic").pack()
name1 = Entry(root,name1 = ticker2).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The code does not work it gives me this error:

> exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance'  objects

The format to get an entry widget in the python GUI looks correct.
I'm using python 2.7 windows 8.1

Comment: I find no mention of a named argument called `name` here http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: To fetch text from an `Entry` use `get()`

Comment: And to bind a StringVar use `e = Entry(master, textvariable=v)` where v is a StringVar, master is the Tkinter instance.

Comment: When you include error messages in your question, at least indicate what line it occurs on — or better yet, include the entire traceback.

Comment: OOo damn it worked 
Thanks man

Comment: @polomint when in doubt, read the docs ;)

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't chain your geometry management. Do `name = Entry(root,foo=bar)` on one line, and then `name.pack()` on the next. Otherwise you end up saving `None` to the `name` variable, which is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `Entry` class constructor has no keyword parameter named `name1`, you can pass a `StringVar` instance to the `textvariable` keyword parameter and retrieve text by calling the get() method on that `StringVar` instance. Alternately, you can just call the get() method on the `Entry` instance itself.

Example:

```
var = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
entry.pack()

var.set('default value')
input = var.get()
```

Comment: You should mention that the OP should use `textvariable` to bind a StringVar

Answer (score 0):

```
    from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
ticker1 = StringVar()
ticker2 = StringVar()
root.title("Choose Companies")
Label(root,
          text = "Company No. 1",
          fg = "black",
          font ="Helvetica 16 italic").pack()
Entry(root,textvariable = ticker1 ).pack()
Label(root,
          text = "Company No. 2",
          fg = "black",
          font ="Helvetica 16 italic").pack()
Entry(root,textvariable = ticker2).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Dude it was bad idea to assigne the entries to the **name** and **name1**. Instead you needed to add the keyword argument called 'textvariable' which is solution to your problem.